# React-Select placeholder is not visible unless I click on the arrow

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Hey everyone I'm using React-Select for the first, ans I've look here to find answer on how styling the width and height of my react-select. Everythings works fine, except that at the begining all the placeholder is not visible. And when I click on the arrow to choose an option, the placeholder appear like magic.
here id my code :
CSS

```css
 const styles = {
        option: (provided, state) => ({
          ...provided,
          fontWeight: state.isSelected ? "bold" : "normal",
          fontSize: "16px",
          width:'95%',
          minHeight: '30px',
          height: '30px',
        }),
        container:(provided) => ({
            ...provided,
          width:'95%',
          minHeight: '30px',
          height: '30px',
        }),
        control:(provided, state) => ({
            ...provided,
          width:'95%',
          minHeight: '35px',
          height: '35px',
          
        }),
        indicators:(provided) => ({
            ...provided,
          width:'95%',
        }),
        valueContainer: (provided) => ({
          ...provided,
          minHeight: '20px',
          height: '20px',
        }),
        indicatorsContainer: (provided) => ({
          ...provided,
          minHeight: '35px',
          height: '35px',
        }),
        placeholder:(provided) => ({
            ...provided,
            height:"20px",
            color: "black",
        }),
      };
```

```js
const options = [ {"value":"standard", "label":"Sélectionnez"}, {"value":1, "label":"Quincy"}, {"value":"2", "label":"Pouilly"}]
<Select
placeholder="Sélectionnez"
options={options} 
onChange={handleChangeSpe}  
styles={styles}/>
```

I've tried :

- Modified the input style, but after the selected options does not show up
- modified height of placeholder
- almost the height of everything that I can modify

Before clicking on the arrow

[image: before clicking on the arrow]

After clicking on the arrow

[image: after clicking on the arrow]

Comment: Did you add placeholder in your options? You didn't add option array so other can check your code and help you

Comment: Yes I added the text of the placeholder, in the place holder option and directly in the options. I also add options array in my code.

Comment: valueContainer: (provided) => ({
            ...provided,
            minHeight: '20px',
            height: '20px',
        }), here height is the issue change it into 30px or 40px and check is it work

Comment: It doesn't change a thing but thank for the answer